# Rust: How to read a file block by block

Tags: file, input, rust, byte, block

i am totally new to rust. I want to read a file block by block/Chunks (every block should contain 16 Bytes) and write it - for this test scenario - into another file, f2. So i i tried it first with this code here:

```
let mut buf = [0;16];
let mut count = 0;

     for byte in f1.bytes() {

            if count  == 16 {
                do_smth(&mut f2, &mut buf);
                count = 0;
                let data = byte?;
                buf[count] = data;

            } else {
                let data = byte?;
                buf[count] = data;
                count +=1;
            }

    }
```

The test bytes in the file f1 were:

`0123456789abcdef-hello world, hello world!`

The result in file f2  was

`0123456789abcdefhello world, hel`

Is there a performant way to increment the file cursor each iteration.
I read about the seek function and experimented a little with it but didn't come to a solution. Maybe this could be solved with an increment of the file cursor each interation?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read

Comment: I read this, but how would i practicaliy do that?
```let n = f.read(&mut buffer[..16])?;```
Does this line increment the file pointer so by the second time the file is read i get the byte 16 to 31?

Comment: yeah thats the general gist of it. You'll have to check that the result is `Ok(n)` and how many `n` bytes were read before you try to `do_smth` with your whole buffer.

Comment: and yeah the file object you're operating on should move the file pointer as it reads; no need to seek manually.

Comment: My last problem is to iterate over the whole file since i always get an error because i read the file twice by calling read on it and iterate on it.

Is there an more elegant way of doing it like this:
```
for _ in reader.bytes() {
        let n = f1.read(&mut buffer[..16])?;
```
Possibly by using

 ```while true {...}``` 

and checking for the lenght of file?
I wanted to avoid while loops since i read that for loops are more performant in rust.

Comment: Why are you trying to both iterate individual bytes and read 16-wide blocks of it simultanously? Just read in a `loop {}`.

Comment: "I wanted to avoid while loops since i read that for loops are more performant in rust" for loops are more efficient for collections (e.g. vecs/slices) than manual indexing but there's no such thing here. Although it could use a `while let` loop e.g. `while let Ok(n) = f.read(&mut buffer)`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b169a56fe54ed6a8778c6d3dc1217ced

Comment: This works pretty good so far, but if the length of the file is no multiple of 16 the "old bytes" of the previous iteration are printed too.

I had in mind to solve it like this:

```
if n != 16 {
            let rest  = &buffer[0..n];
            write_to_new_file(&mut file2, &rest);
        }
```

But this does not work as intended.
A match constisting of 15 arms would be very ugly.
Is there a better way?

Comment: Nevermind, i forgot to
```
break
```
after the last writing process.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working solution.

```
let mut buffer = [0; 16];
let mut count = 0;
while let Ok(n) = f1.read(&mut buffer[..]) {
    if n != 16 {
        let rest = &buffer[0..n];
        do_smth(&mut f2, &rest);
        break;
    } else {
        do_smth(&mut f2, &mut buffer);
        count += n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two thing you could consider in order to improve performance:

1. Wrapping `File` in a `BufReader` to reduce the number of system calls and essentially chunking your file access.
2. You might want to check out the [memmap crate](https://crates.io/crates/memmap), to use a memory mapped file.