# What is the proper way to search a file byte-by-byte?

Tags: parsing, rust

In parsing a file, I need to locate a certain valued byte. In this case, I am searching for the value `13`. I know that this value will exist at the start of a 32-byte block. With all of that information, I have come up with a few solutions similar to the following:

```
let mut file = File::open("file_to_open").unwrap();
let mut read_array = [0u8;32];
while read_array[0] != 13 {
    file.read_exact(&mut read_array).unwrap();
}
[...]
```

The problem with this is it takes a very long time. Running this code 100,000 times, for instance, takes around 9 seconds. On the other hand, if I load a large amount of data into a `Vec` and then search through memory, I can read it much faster. But, the file is large and if I load too big of a chunk at a time, it will take longer than reading byte-by-byte in cases where the data would have been found early in the file. I tried using SeekFrom::Current, but seeking forward 32 bytes was slower than just reading all 32 bytes at once.

Is my only option to come up with an acceptable *chunk size* and iterate those chunks?

Edit:

The following is currently my quickest implementation:

```
fn get_raw(file: &mut File) -> usize {
    let start_bit= 32;
    let mut iter = 0;
    file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(start_bit)).unwrap();
    let read_size = 32;
    let block_size = read_size * 100;
    let mut my_vec = vec![0u8;block_size];
    while let Ok(n) = file.read(&mut my_vec) {
        if n != block_size {
            break;
        }
        for i in (0..block_size).step_by(read_size) {
            if my_vec[i] == 13 {
                return iter;
            }
            iter += 1;
        }
    }
    panic!("The database is corrupt; this process cannot continue.");
}
```

Comment: 1) When benchmarking, did you remember to compile in release mode? 2) You should probably use a `BufReader` to read from the file: `let mut file = BufReader::new(File::open("file_to_open").unwrap());`

Comment: Speed differences between debug and release for this particular code is almost non-existent. I will check out BufReader for this.

Comment: BufReader speeds up the byte-array method by a large amount. However, it's still about half the speed when compared to loading 3200 bytes into a Vec.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61352882/rust-how-to-read-a-file-block-by-block) might be helpful

Comment: I've added some sample code to the question. The sample code is the quickest I've been able to get the code to run. Anytime I lower `block_size` the time it takes to run increases by a lot. As written it takes 576 milliseconds to run 100,000 times. Changing it to `let block_size = read_size *10` increases the time take to about 1,500 milliseconds.

Comment: I should add, with the current block-size, only ONE file read occurs. It seems that the read itself is heavy. That's where my original question comes in. I am not sure how to find the balance between the cost of read itself and the cost of reading too much.

Comment: One thing I have found: `SeekFrom::Current` takes about twice as long as `SeekFrom::Start`